# htaccess does not redirect when uploading Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Yesterday, I uploaded a Wordpress site on "**public_html/wordpress**" folder for testing purpose. It worked fine. The URL was "**mysite/wordpress**".

But today, I deleted the "**wordpress**" folder, uploaded Wordpress src again to the upper level "**public_html**" folder. However when I went to "**mysite.com**", it still redirects to "**mysite/wordpress**". And of course, a 404 error appears because I had previously deleted the "**wordpress**" folder.

Even if I typed "**mysite.com/index.php**", it still redirected to the wrong place "**public_html/wordpress**"

This is ALL the content of the .htaccess file on "**public_html**".

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I'm completely new to wordpress, please helps me ASAP.

Comment: you don't need to rename and all, just go through permalink settings and save that again. it will works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to permalink configuration in Wordpress. If WP admin is loading then visit `permalink setting` page and change all links to remove `/wordpress` from URLs.

If WP admin is not coming up then via PHPMyAdmin update `wp_options` table to fix all URLs that have `/wordpress` in them. (`option_id=39` is one of them).

Comment: after visiting `wp_options`, I saw 2 entries with option_name of `siteurl` and `home`. Those are all configued to `http://mysite.com` as default. And the `Permalink` seems fine, too

Comment: Then rename wordpress directory to something else try it out in a new browser to avoid browser caching.